Calculating limit with given integral
I have got this question as homework:
given function $f(x)$ that is continuous and positive in $[0,1]$.

Show that for each $n \in \mathbb{N} $ there is $x_n \in [0,\dfrac{1}{2}]$
such that
$$\dfrac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, dx=\int_{0}^{x_n} f(x) \, dx+\int_{1-x_n}^{1} f(x) \, dx$$ 
and find $\lim_{n \to \infty} n x_n$

I solved the first part of the Question by defining function $g(x)$ as
$$g(x)=\int_{0}^{x} f(t) \, dt+\int_{1-x}^{1} f(t) \, dt$$
$$A=\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx$$
Using ivt we get that g(x) gets every value between 0 and A, So, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there is $x_n$ such that
$$g(x_n)=\frac{A}{n}$$.
$$A=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^1 f(x)dx=g(x_n)$$
That is the first part of the question, how can i continue?
thanks for the helping!

Correct the definition of $g$ (change the variable in the integrands) and show how you applied the IVP theorem

from the first part you get that
$$\frac{1}{n}\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\int_0^{x_n} f(x)dx+\int_{1-x_n}^1 f(x)dx$$
using the mean value theorem we get:
$$x_n\cdot f(c_n)+x_n\cdot f(d_n)= \frac{1}{n}\int_0^1 f(x)dx$$
$c_n\in [0,x_n]$, $d_n\in [1-x_n,1]$
$$nx_n=\frac{1}{f(c_n)+f(d_n)}\int_0^1 f(x)dx$$
easily you can show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = 0$, from that and from the squeeze theory we get that $\lim_{n\to\infty} c_n = 0$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty} d_n = 1$.
finaly we get that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} nx_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{f(c_n)+f(d_n)}\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\frac{1}{f(0)+f(1)}\int_0^1 f(x)dx$$
